# How can I delete the default Constraint Layout of a blank activity?

Tags: android

When I create a new project in Android studio, and choose a blank activity, there is a default Constraint Layout attached.

I'm trying to follow some online tutorials with a Grid layout, but it's not working as expected because of the constraint layout.

The tutorial is a couple years old so I'm guessing the constraint layout was part of an update.

Is it possible to get rid of this constraint layout?

Below is the default XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.user1.gridlayoutApp.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: just delete the layout and add your own

Comment: Go to the Text mode for the layout, select the ConstraintLayout root and wipe it. Insert your own.

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro Hi, I've tried right-clicking on the layout in the component tree, but it won't leave me delete it for some reason

Comment: @pulp_fiction Hi, I've posted my XML above. When I go to this text mode, and remove the above code, I can't add anything else from the Design mode.

Comment: You need a root view first. Add a root ViewGroup(LinearLayout or FrameLayout, etc.) and then add on top of it whatever you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can just remove ConstraintLayout tags and add LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Close your IDE and then open again with the help of internet access to update it..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).